# changing android Manifest.xml

Tags: java, android

I have an android project that create other android app using zip and zipSigner. This app works great but i need to change the app name and package name in manifest so user can create different apps.

I have download  [this library](https://codeload.github.com/sjitech/ApkRename/zip/master) to parse xml from the apk but dont know how to use it using java.

Can anyone give some ways to use it or maybe other library?

i see that apk editor, apk tool can modify it.

Comment: That file (and so are all the resources) is **untouchable** at run time.

Comment: You can change it at build time, but not at runtime

Comment: yes that is what im doing

Comment: The library you are referencing is open source, just look at the source code: https://github.com/sjitech/ApkRename/blob/master/lib/AndroidManifestBinaryXml_ChangePackageName/src/jp/sji/sumatium/tool/AndroidManifestBinaryXml_ChangePackageName.java

Comment: `programmatically ...` means you want to do that at runtime. And you **can't**.

Comment: @Kling Klang you can see the example with apk editor.The apk name and packge name can be modified based on user input.

Comment: Not `programmatically`. I mean the apk editor is an app which is operating on another app. By the way, this is quite piratesque.

Comment: ok, but my app does not editing other app. I want to modify my other so the user can create apps and install it as different apps. if manifest were not changed, the user will just replacing his old app with new apps.

Comment: I'm not able to make sense of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive already solve it:

[this](https://github.com/8enet/apkeditor) library give me a good work